# Nativescript/Angular TextView how to disallow certain values?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I want to allow the user to edit a textview; however, if the value is invalid (sets it to 0 for example) it will revert to the value before the edit.  Is there a way to do this in just the .html file?

```
  <TextView
        [editable]="lift.completed"
        keyboardType="number"
        [text]="lift.reps"
        row="0"
        col="3"
        class="set_list"
        (textChange)="updateLifts(i, 'reps', $event.value)"
      >
```

Comment: You will need to implement the functionality somewhere besides the html file but once you have done that, you can make it available via a directive

Comment: You can listen to change event on text field, when you find the new value is invalid you can set the value to its old one. As Aluan mentioned, you would even write it as a directive if you like to reuse.

Comment: @Manoj indeed. I think we can't just do it all in a `(change)` inline handler is because we need some consistent way to store and retrieve the previous valid value. I could be wrong about that though

Comment: I think the property change event already gives you old value, try logging the event object.

Comment: Sorry I just added some of the code.  I have it being sent through a function that will only update the value that the text is set to if it is within my specified parameters; however, visually the textfield is staying as the invalid value.  I'm not sure if there's a way I can send the textview itself as a parameter and modify the value within a function in typescript?

Answer (score -1):

wouldn't the simple solution be to use input?

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100">
```

That appears to solve every requirement you provided in your description.